# How do i add audio to my program? I have a mp3 already in my program

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have in my index.html this already, and then i add a function named play where i call in play to my script file[then finally when i try to call in my play command if the player decides to shoot a fireball at the enemy it gives me an error saying "Cannot read property 'play' of null" What do i do?

I have this in my index.html file:

```
<audio id="audio" src="fire.mp3" ></audio>
```

At the top of my script file, i do this:

```
var fire = new Audio();
fire.src = "fire.mp3";
function play(){
   var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
   audio.play();
             }`


 (Fire.mp3 is already a file outside of my program, its what i called in in my   index.html file)
```

Lastly, when the player decides to use fireball, I tried to add the one second fireball noise in by doing this:

```
if (fire = true && up2 === "FIRE" ) {
  var  enemyhealth = parseInt(enemyhealth) - parseInt(firepower);
  xp + 2;
  play();
```

`
play at the end is when i try to call in the function, but it dosent work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to get the best answers, you will need to post code examples. This article explains how to ask a great question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `=` does not compare things.

Answer (score 0):

You're using inconsistent methods and objects. Change your code to this:

```
var fire = document.getElementById("audio");
```

Or this:

```
var fire = new Audio("fire.mp3");
```

And then make sure it's still consistent all the way through your program.

Comment: Hey Jack, so i did that. I deleted all of the code above and in the script at the very top i typed in 'var fireaudio = new Audio("fire.mp3");' then at the time i wanted the audio to play i put 'fireaudio()'. I ran the program, and it came back and said '
script.js:44 Uncaught TypeError: fireaud is not a function'

Comment: You need to play it. Use `fireaudio.play()` and it will work perfectly.